# Install the MySQL driver to work with GDAL on Mac OSX

Tags: python, gdal

How can I install the MySQL Driver to work with GDAL?
I have currently followed the following steps on my Mac:

1. Installed python 3.8 from python.org
2. Ran the following command to install gdal `brew install gdal`
3. Upgraded gdal to the latest version `brew upgrade gdal`
4. Checked the gdal version info using `gdalinfo --version` and response `GDAL 3.1.2, released 2020/07/07`
5. Installed gdal with python `pip install gdal`
6. Ran the following  snippet from the ogr cookbook to check for the available drivers

```
from osgeo import ogr
cnt = ogr.GetDriverCount()
formatsList = []  # Empty List

for i in range(cnt):
  driver = ogr.GetDriver(i)
  driverName = driver.GetName()
  if not driverName in formatsList:
      formatsList.append(driverName)

formatsList.sort() # Sorting the messy list of ogr drivers

for i in formatsList:
  print (i)
```

but did not find the mysql driver in the list

```
JPEG2000
KML
MBTiles
MSSQLSpatial
MVT
MapInfo File
MapML
Memory
```

I even tried installing the mysql-connector-python
and

```
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
brew install osgeo-gdal-mysql
```

but no luck with that either.